# How to recover to the factory settings after installing the AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I flashed AOSP (4.2.2) to a Nexus 7 tablet.

Is there any way that I can recover it back to its factory setting (with the product version of Android)?

Comment: I think this belongs better here (http://android.stackexchange.com/). To answer your question I believe you have to flash back using a stock image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash back using these stock images:

[Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

Comment: Any instructions to follow?

Comment: (http://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-7-rooting-roms-hacks/191477-guide-nexus-7-factory-image-restore.html)